# How to deserialize JSON to objects of the correct type, without having to define the type before hand?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I searched through similar questions and couldn't find anything that quite matched what i was looking for.

New to C# so bear with me please.

I have some json files that i am deserializing. I want the files to deserialize to objects of the correct type, without having to define the type before hand. Here's my code:

```
public class loadJson
    {
        //path of the file location
        public void readJson(string path)
        {
            //array of files at the path location. right now just reading one file
            FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("seleniumExample.json").ToArray();

            foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
            {

                dynamic b1 = null;
                using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(fi.FullName))
                {

                    string fileText = file.ReadToEnd();
                    //Console.WriteLine(fileText);

                    try
                    {
                        b1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileText);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR!!!! " + e.ToString());
                    }

                    file.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a bunch of object types that I will be feeding into my program through json files.

I don't want to have to explicitly call b1 a Bid, or a Client, or any other specific predefined class. If I do explicitly call b1 a Bid, it loads all the info just fine and fills out the correct instance variables.

But when I use "dynamic", or general "object", it can't figure it out and just initializes to an "object".

Is there a way to perform generic deserialization and have it create an object of the correct class based on the fields defined in the json file?

Thanks in advance for the help, and i apologize if my question is incredibly unclear. If so, please just let me know how I can help clear up any ambiguity. Thanks again.

Comment: `Is there a way to perform generic deserialization and have it create an object of the correct class based on the fields defined in the json file?` Suppose Json.Net guessed the *correct* class and returned that object. How would you use it in your code? You still don't know the type of `b1` while writing your code.

Comment: So, my thinking is this: Instead of writing one of these readJson() methods for every class that I am going to potentially feed into my program as a JSON file, I thought I could just do it in a generic fashion and not have to reuse too much code. Does that not make sense? Again, I'm new to c# and software development in general, so I'm open to the idea that this might not be the best way to go.

Comment: Do you have the ability to control the format & contents of the JSON files?  Or are they a given?

Comment: I have the ability to control the format and contents.

Comment: Do all the JSON files in the directory store objects of the same type?

Comment: No. and that's why i want to be able to deserialize in a generic fashion.

Comment: @kdeez - Then does `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` meet your needs?

Answer (score 22):

Json.NET has the ability to record the .Net object type of polymorphic types during serialization, by using the setting [`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).  When the setting is enabled the .Net type of polymorphic objects will appear as a synthetic property called `"$type"`, [for instance](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm):

> ```
> "$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Samples.Stockholder, Newtonsoft.Json.Tests"
> ```

However, the `"$type"` property is never emitted for the **root** object if you call the conventional methods [`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) or [`JsonSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter, Object)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_2.htm).  Instead, you must use one of the serialization methods that accepts an "expected" root type, for instance [`SerializeObject(Object, Type, JsonSerializerSettings)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject_7.htm) or [`JsonSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter, Object, Type)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize_3.htm).  Passing `typeof(object)` as the expected type guarantees the type property will appear:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject, typeof(object), settings);
```

If you create your JSON files using this setting, the JSON itself will remember the type of object serialized.  This type will be used by Json.NET during deserialization, as long as you use set `TypeNameHandling` to something other than [`TypeNameHandling.None`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm). e.g.:

```
var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Auto };
b1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fileText, settings);
```

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w0y8aI).

Caveats: this way of storing .Net types in JSON is nonstandard.  Other serializers such as [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do not process type information in this format.

Note also this caution from the [Newtonsoft docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. Incoming types should be validated with a custom SerializationBinder when deserializing with a value other than None.

For a discussion of why this may be necessary, see [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182), [How to configure Json.NET to create a vulnerable web API](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html), and Alvaro Muñoz & Oleksandr Mirosh's blackhat paper https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf.

Comment: Even, if the Json was serialized using `$type`, the non-generic `DeserializeObject` overload will (at least for the root object) not use the converter. See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374760/why-does-jsonconvert-deserializeobject-not-use-the-specified-jsonconverter

Comment: if $type is specified, `DeserializeObject` returns that type (and not e.g JToken), see the example in the other question, linked above

Comment: @mike - you're right.  I never use the non-generic version so I had forgotten exactly how that particular method processes `"$type"`.  I added a link to an updated fiddle to confirm the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Deserialize your JSON into the most basic form:

```
Dictionary<string, object> theData= new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);

string baseItemName = (string)theData["baseItem"];

Dictionary<string, object> someNode= (Dictionary<string, object>)theData["something"];

string anything = (string)someNode["anything"];
string nothing = (string)someNode["nothing"];
```

The call to `Deserialize()` creates a tree of `Dictionary<string, object>` that you can traverse at will.