# .net property won't deserialize from json to .net object

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am using newtonsoft to deserialize objects like so :

```
var profile  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Profile>(payload.Payload)
```

Here is the 'Profile' I want to create from the JSON I'm getting

```
public class Profile
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "$type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Which looks like this :

```
{ "$type": "NWS.Plugin.Customers.Customer, NWS.Plugin.Customers",  "UserName": "example1_1",...}
```

For whatever reason I am unable to get '$type' to be anything but null. It *can* be null but even when it's not upon deserializing without error it becomes null. Any help as to what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize JSON to objects of the correct type, without having to define the type before hand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688498/how-to-deserialize-json-to-objects-of-the-correct-type-without-having-to-define). Use `new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto }` when deserializing.

Comment: @Jawad `TypeNameHandling.Auto` most probably cause an exception, because OP wants to deserialize a `$type` into the string property in object of type `Profile`, which is defined already, not to `NWS.Plugin.Customers.Customer, NWS.Plugin.Customers`

Comment: @Andrew Why do you need to deserialize a json into `Profile` class instead of `NWS.Plugin.Customers.Customer, NWS.Plugin.Customers`, which was written during serilalization? `$type` is type information, included to json during serialization. Do you need it as `string` only? You can try a `JObject` for that

Comment: Also, for deserialization you should use [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) with caution, because external types can have some vulnerabilities, look through this [article](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html) for details