# Use System.Text.Json with Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, system.text.json

I was having trouble finding a JSON serialization/deserialization solution that was compatible with the latest LTS version of Unity (2022.3.9f1), with the issue being that this was specifically needed for an external class library that needed to be shared with software NOT including any Unity Runtime libraries and I also needed the `JsonElement` accessibility into the JSON, at least at this point for debugging purposes, without needing to have detailed classes for every single payload.  So basically JSON.NET wasn't going to work, it had to be System.Text.Json, and between target frameworks and dependencies there were numerous obstacles to getting that working with Unity.

I *EXPECTED* to be able to just `using System.Text.Json;` in my class library's source file and have it obey me like a good computer should.  However by targeting the .NET Standard 2.1 framework in order to create a class library Unity can load without sputtering and dying, I'm too early to have that namespace included by default without getting it from NuGet.  Ok, fine, except the latest version doesn't support .NET Standard 2.1, I need to upgrade my target framework, but I can't because Unity.

Ok, so I can roll back to 6.0.9 on System.Text.Json and the warnings about the target framework go away.  Dev work on the library, all is going well, back to Unity to reimport the updated library, and nope.  Library won't be included because references are missing or incompatible and therefore Assembly won't be built because of errors in library.

Problem is that System.Text.Json @ 6.0.9 needs to be in the `plugins` for the Unity Project and so do three of its dependencies:

- System.Text.Encodings.Web @ 6.0.0
- System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe @ 6.0.0
- Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces @ 6.0.0

The dlls can all be found in the `build` folders if you view these references from Visual Studio under the "Packages" tree in the Solution Explorer and "Open Folder in File Explorer" on the System.Text.Json package.

If there's a better way to do this, by all means clue me in, but none of the answers I found actually worked or were this (relatively) straightforward.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what your limitations regarding Json.NET are .. What exactly is you intended use-case if not (de)serializing to/from specific type implementations? Otherwise maybe this could suit your use case https://stackoverflow.com/a/31035131/7111561 .. or you could go fully [`dynamic`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm)

Comment: The easiest way I've found for full Json support is to open Package Manager => click the `[+]` dropdown in the upper left => select "Add packages by name..." => enter: com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json -- but I don't know if Newtonsoft will addresses your JsonElement requirement.

Comment: unity comes with a json provider, whats the issue with it?

Comment: *I also needed the `JsonElement` accessibility into the JSON* -- The equivalent type in Json.NET is [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) from [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) which can be sued to deserialize free-form JSON with no fixed schema.  I'd recommend using `JToken` explicitly over `dynamic`.

Comment: Thanks @dbc, that sounds like the solution I was looking for.  If I go back to the issue I'll give that a shot.  The limitations with Json.NET (the JSON provider that comes with Unity, even though I explicitly need JSON support OUTSIDE of Unity) were that I had not been able to find the documentation about the JToken type that sounds like it offers the kind of "rapid-prototyping" JSON access I needed without creating basically one-time use types for every payload.  My secondary purpose in posting though was to provide better documentation for getting System.Text.Json to run in Unity.